# Find the first or third column

Tags: shell, awk, grep

The following command is working as expected. What I need to find is the thread id that is available in the first or third column.

```
# tail -1000 general.log | grep Connect | egrep -v "(abc|slave_user)"
                2856057 Connect root@localhost on 
111116  5:14:01 2856094 Connect root@localhost on
```

If the line starts with the date, select the third column i.e. 2856094 or the first column i.e. 2856057

```
Expected output:
2856057
2856094
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to look at it is that you always take the fourth column when counting from the right:

```
awk '{ print $(NF-3) }'
```

Otherwise, if the date is really the only reliable indicator, try this:

```
awk -v Date=$(date "+%y%m%d") '$1 == Date { print $3; next } { print $1 }'
```

Comment: I would suggest "Connect" as the indicator: `awk '{print $2=="Connect" ? $1 : $3}'`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `awk '{print ($2=="Connect" ? $1 : $3)}'`

Answer (score 1):

If your data really is that regular (i.e. all the columns are fixed width), then you could use `cut`:

```
tail -1000 general.log | grep Connect | egrep -v "(abc|slave_user)" | cut -c17-23
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 tail -1000 general.log | sed -e '/abc\|slave_user/d;/ Connect.*/!d;s///;s/.* //'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the awk inbuilt variable NF to capture the number of fields. If they equal to 6 then print 3 column else print 1st column.

```
awk 'NF==6{ print $3;next } { print $1 }' INPUT_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the format of the file, maybe try:

```
$ tail -1000 general.log | grep Connect | egrep -v "(abc|slave_user)" | awk '{if ($3 == "root@localhost"){print $1;}else{print $3}}'
```

Or maybe this would work which is simpler:

```
$ awk '/Connect/ {if ($3 == "root@localhost"){print $1;}else{print $3}}' general.log
```

I tried. If I'm wrong, or there is a better way, I to will learn it in time. :)

Maybe this using int() ??????

```
$ awk '/Connect/ {if (!int($3)){print $1;}else{print $3}}' general.log
```

Comment: This is close. What I need is this - awk '{if ($3 == "is not a number"){print $1;}else{print $3}}'

Comment: maybe this: $ awk '/Connect/ {if (!int($3)){print $1;}else{print $3}}' general.log